# Crashlytics - Why do i need to download dSYMs before uploading them?

Tags: ios, crashlytics, twitter-fabric, fabric.io

i have created a new archive on xcode, uploaded it for publishing on the store, and now i want to include the dSYMs in Fabric Crashlytics and i have four options:

1. upload [APP_NAME].dsym (extracted from the archive)
2. upload all dSYMs files (extracted from the archive)
3. upload all dSYMs files + UUID dSYMs files (extracted from the archive after clicking download dSYMs)
4. upload the zip file downloaded from itunesconnect

after trying all the above, i have noticed that number 4 is the only one solution that succeeded to remove the missing dSYMs message from Fabric Crashlytics. Note that i used `mdfind "com_apple_xcode_dsym_uuids == <UUID>"` with the missing UUID on my local computer and found the missing UUID only in solution 3 (did not find any in solution 1 and 2).

My question now is what's the difference between the 4 solutions and why did solution 4 only work ?

Answer (score 1):

Are you building with "bitcode enabled" set to true? In that case, Apple is recreating the dSYMs after you upload your app, and therefore Crashlytics needs that new file.

See https://docs.fabric.io/apple/crashlytics/missing-dsyms.html

Answer (score 0):

I am consider that you have following the right steps to install the crashlatics into the iOS app , Xcode.

Their is simple  solution to your problem.
You have to follow the steps mention below.

1. Before archive your app . Please clean your project (command+k).

2.Now you have to build your Project (command +b). It is available below the “archive” option.

3. Finally archive your app.

Now your app is available on fabric.io
(You can cross check with the version no. Of the app.)